# Different xhdpi dimens.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen-support, galaxy-nexus

I started to develop android apps. I created values folder xhdpi:

There are two different xhdpi resolution.

Dimens.xml values are the same in both resolution reads :/

Galaxy Nexus 720x1280(xhdpi) - Nexus 4 768x1280 (xhdpi) and Nexus 7 1200x1920 I don't understand :/

How do I separate these three dimens.xml values?

[image]

Comment: Could you please be more precise on what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by 'separate these three dimens.xml values`?

Comment: Hi Nexus 7 Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus I want to define separate dimens.xml file. it is possible ?